# Is there any advantage using matrices instead of equations do describe a trochoid?

Tags: matrices

I was reading this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/173987/how-can-i-relate-linear-and-angular-motion-using-a-single-formula/174209#174209) at Physics SE, where a lengthy explanation is given to describe a trochoid, the combination of linear and rotational motion of a rod.

Can you explain what is the point/ advantages of using such a complex method inseatd of a simple and elegant [equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trochoid#General_description)?

I think the author is interested in computer simulations is that a situation that makes obligatory the use of matrices?

Can you describe all the content of the post with an equation?

Comment: Matrices provide a nice framework for describing manipulations of systems of linear equations. Other than the practical advantages in actually working with a system of equations in matrix form, personally I find that form to be more clear and elegant, especially for larger systems. Also, at first glance it looks like the complex part of that answer isn't the use of matrices, but the use of inertia and momenta...

Answer (score 1):

Matrices are computer friendly notations. If you want to feed some information to  computer, you have to smash it to make it looks like a matrix.

If you want to compute, for example, perturbations in an airplane you have to transform your airplane into a matrix and operate on it.

I would like to add, that with matrices you have simple as plain operations that act over the matrix (jordan simplification, lu decomposition, ...) these allied with parallel computing can make things work real fast.

Today GPUs (graphical processing units) are able to get large matrices and operate a large number of elements in a single operation. Instead iterating over an matrix these can improve hugely the processing time therefore raising the modern computational capabilities.

In the end, on computers everything is about matrices and polynomials.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, sure it helps, but can you specify if, apart from PC's, they are more powervul than equations? can you write down the simplest system of equations that  describes the issue like matrices? Also, is the explanation perfectly OK or is there room for improvement? Is it all clear to you?

Comment: For example, every high order (high here means greater than 1) differential equation can be splitted in n (where n is the order) single order differential equations, put in a system of equations (that means you will have a matrix) and be calculated as that. 

In fact that is the technique used to find  numerical solutions of any differential equation in any computing language.

Comment: Just look for "System ODE" in math.SE and you will find many examples. There is many videos about this topic on Youtube (for example www.youtube.com/watch?v=cq3bPBePE8E )